# Making an app that cycles through all possible RGBA color combinations

Tags: java, android, colors, rgba

I was wondering how to make it so that when you click on a button, it starts a loop that cycles through all of the possible combinations for RGBA colors using a random number generator. I was trying to accomplish this by making an object class that creates all of the possible combinations and puts them into an ArrayList, which then selects one possible RGBA combination at random.

Here's my code for my **MainActivity**

```
package com.example.safteyprecautions;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Random rand1;
    private Random rand2;
    private Random rand3;
    private Random rand4;
    private int r;
    private int g;
    private int b;
    private int a;
    private RGBASelector rgba;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button pressMe = findViewById(R.id.pressMe);
        final LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
//        rand1 = new Random(255);
//        rand2 = new Random(255);
//        rand3 = new Random(255);
//        rand4 = new Random(100);
        rgba = new RGBASelector(255, 255, 255, 100);
        pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                r = rgba.getR();
//                g = rgba.getG();
//                b = rgba.getB();
//                a = rgba.getA();
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, r, 0, 0));
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Let the fun begin!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**My Object Class**

```
package com.example.safteyprecautions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class RGBASelector
{
    private int r;
    private int g;
    private int b;
    private int a;
    private int[] RGBAValues;
    private ArrayList <Integer> RGBA;
    private Random rand;

    public RGBASelector(int rRange, int gRange, int bRange, int aRange)
    {
        r = rRange;
        g = gRange;
        b = bRange;
        a = aRange;
        rand = new Random(255);
        RGBAValues = new int[rRange];
        RGBA = new ArrayList <>();
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            RGBAValues[i] = i;
            RGBA.add(RGBAValues[i]);
        }
    }

//    public void createRGBAValues()
//    {
//        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
//        {
//            RGBAValues[i] = i;
//        }
//    }

    public int getR()
    {
        r = rand.nextInt();
        return RGBA.get(r);
    }

    public int getG()
    {
        return g;
    }

    public int getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

And my **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to "
        android:fontFamily="cursive" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pressMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PRESS ME!!!"
        android:fontFamily="cursive" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you're wanting to store the colors in an array, as opposed to generating the color on the fly? There are a few ways we could generate a random color without an array of 4.3 billion values. Or the limited 1.7 billion in your case with the limited alpha range.

Comment: That's 6.7GB in size!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler to create an event loop where you re-call a method. and you can check the state of the button and then either update or not. mine is in kotlin but is close. Created a quick proof of concept. For my layout it is just the constraint layout with a plain `View` that takes up everything and the button.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var pressed = false
val handler = Handler()
lateinit var task: Runnable

val colors = arrayOf(Color.RED, Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val bg: View = findViewById(R.id.background)
    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.doThings)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        pressed = !pressed
        if (pressed)
            handler.post(task)
    }

        task= Runnable {
            if (pressed){
                bg.setBackgroundColor(colors[Random.nextInt(colors.size)])

                handler.post(task)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create a task that if active will do work and re call it's self.

in the button handler. set the state of the button and if active call the task. 
Delays can be added if colors are too fast.